# why is exception calss reference variable print the message in java?

Tags: java, tostring

i am new in java i don not understand that why exception class reference variable print the message and reference variable  of normal class print the eclassname@jsjka why ?

```
public class Exception11 {
    int x,y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        int total;
        Exception11 e=new Exception11();
        e.x=10;
        e.y=0;
        total=10/0;
        System.out.println("Value of refernce variable: "+e);
        System.out.println(total);
        } catch (ArithmeticException h) {
            System.out.println("number can not divide by the 0 Please try again");
            int total;
            Exception11 e=new Exception11();
            System.out.println("Value of refernce variable: "+e);
            System.out.println("Value of refernce variable: "+h);



        }

    }

}
```

answer -----------------------------

```
number can not divide by the 0 Please try again
Value of refernce variable: Exception11@4f1d0d
Value of refernce variable: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: And what is the relation to JavaEE?

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing the [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) representation of your class. In contrast `ArithmeticException` already overrides this method. You need to override this method in `Exception11`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Exception11 [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `System.out.println("..." + e)` will invoke the `toString()` method of `Exception11 e`. Since the `Exception11` class doesn't have a `toString()` method, it inherits `Object`'s `toString()` method, which returns a `String` with the value:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

This is where `Exception11@4f1d0d` comes from. You must implement `toString()` in your `Exception11` class and have it return whatever string you want the error to be named.

See [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for details on the `Object`'s `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `h.toString()` and `e.toString()`. Since `ArithmeticException` has an overridden custom `toString` that is printed.

With your class, the default is printed, namely the class name followed by `@` followed by the identity hash code in hex.

You can override as:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //your logic to construct a string that you feel
       // textually represents the content of your Exception11
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArithmeticException` uses `Throwable#toString()` implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    String s = getClass().getName();
    String message = getLocalizedMessage();
    return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
}
```

while your class `Exception11` uses the default `Object#toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```